# data size decrease when uploaded to Hbase

Tags: linux, hadoop, nosql, hbase

When files are uploaded to Hbase table as records from linux machine, we are observing reduction in data size (10 GB  on file system ~ 6-8 GB in Hbase table). There is no compression method employed on the hbase table and major compaction is disabled too. Unable to find the reason for the reason??

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the records are stored on the Linux machine. If they're JSON then each key is stored with each value, which can massively increase the file size. HBase stores data in a much more optimised columnar format that discards keys.

Even if you're not using JSON and don't have compression enabled, HBase will still utilise optimisations to reduce file size.